# Is there an easy way to picture a Whitney embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I just encountered this theorem for the first time but find it very difficult to picture.
This is how it's presented in my course in the simplest case
[image]

But for an example in the case where the manifold is $S^1$ and we are using the antipodal charts how would this embedding look like in $\mathbb{R}^4$? Is this the wrong way to approach this topic?

Edit: if we identify the circle as the set of angles $\theta$ then the antipodal map becomes $2tan(\theta/2)$ this can be scaled to an unit interval using the arctangent function so it can be reduced to a map of the form $\theta\mapsto\theta$. There will be two such maps one which is centered around $0$ the other around $\pi$. The bump function will be $e^{\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}}}=b$ for short hand. The induced Whitney embedding will have to be something of the form $\theta\mapsto(\theta b(\theta),b(\theta),\theta b(\theta),b(\theta))$ I know there are some issues with the other chart but I chose to ignore them for now. If we look at what goes on in a single plane $\theta\mapsto(\theta b(\theta),b(\theta))$ I graphed this and got:

[image]

The way I picture what is going on is we have that as we go around $S^1$ we are moving in a circle (something homeomorphic to one at least) in two planes of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Am I going about it in the right way? How do I use this for a more general intuition?

Comment: It's not at all the wrong way to work through this proof, on the contrary it may be very enlightening. So, using two antipodal charts for $S^1$, what happened when you wrote down the two bump functions, one per chart, and worked through the proof?

Comment: @LeeMosher I just edited my post